# Passing a value, which is changing, from one class to another

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, view

I have the value "count" in my View class, and Ihave my MainActivity, which is requesting the "count" value and that is working fine. But the value "count" is increasing whenever the screen is touched, so this value changes, but in the MainActivity, I always get the "count" value from the first request, and not the different increased "count". I want to know, how I could manage that the request always gets the new "count" value..

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.drawproject;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1; //Gelb
Button b2; //Blau
Button b3; //Grün       


Integer Pcount2 = DrawArea.getCountValue(); //get the count value

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.drawlayout);
DrawArea da = new DrawArea(this, null);

if(Pcount2 % 2 == 1){ //use it -> it's always the same number, instead of the increased
    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(this, ChangeArea.class);
    startActivity(nextScreen);
}
else{
    Pcount2++;

}

}
}
```

**ViewClass**

```
package com.example.drawproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class DrawArea extends View {

private List<Stroke> _allStrokes; //all strokes that need to be drawn
private SparseArray<Stroke> _activeStrokes; //use to retrieve the currently drawn strokes
private Random _rdmColor = new Random();


static int count = 1; // count is 1

public DrawArea(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);

_allStrokes = new ArrayList<Stroke>();
_activeStrokes = new SparseArray<Stroke>();
setFocusable(true);
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

}


public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
if (_allStrokes != null) {
    for (Stroke stroke: _allStrokes) {
        if (stroke != null) {
            Path path = stroke.getPath();
            Paint painter = stroke.getPaint();
            if ((path != null) && (painter != null)) {
                if(count%2 != 0){
                canvas.drawPath(path, painter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
final int action = event.getActionMasked();
final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        count++; // count increases +1
        if(count%2 != 1)
        {pointDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY(), event.getPointerId(0));
        break;
        }
        if (count%2 != 0){
            for (int pc = 0; pc < pointerCount; pc++) {
                pointDown((int)event.getX(pc), (int)event.getY(pc), event.getPointerId(pc));
    }
        }
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        break;
    }

}
invalidate();
return true;
}

public static Integer getCountValue(){

Integer count2 = count; //get the count value to pass it to the other class
return count2;


}

private void pointDown(int x, int y, int id) {

Integer value = ChangeArea.getColorValue();

if(count%2 !=1){
//create a paint with random color
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

if (value == 1){

paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
    }else
    if (value == 2){

        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        }else
    if (value == 3){

        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }
    else{

    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    if (value == 1){

    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }else
    if (value == 2){

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }else
    if (value == 3){

        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    else{
        paint.setColor(_rdmColor.nextInt()); //Here should the values be added!
    }
//create the Stroke
Point pt = new Point(x, y);
Stroke stroke = new Stroke(paint);
stroke.addPoint(pt);
_activeStrokes.put(id, stroke);
_allStrokes.add(stroke);
}

if (count%2 != 0){
//retrieve the stroke and add new point to its path
Stroke stroke = _activeStrokes.get(id);
if (stroke != null) {
    Point pt = new Point(x, y);
    stroke.addPoint(pt);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: I have seen this question ....viewactivity is not an activity,its a view

Comment: @DividebyZero my fault, I wrote the false name! it's view class... but my problem is that, the value "count" is always the same in the main activity, but in the view class it is changing...

Comment: You should add that detail to the question @gewhjhfkgad

Comment: I added it to the question @JFit

Comment: anyone knows the answer? ._.

Comment: There is only one getCountValue call in your MainAvtivity. When do you expect it will be called? Put the call in onCreate.

Comment: @greenapps aa thank you such a stupid mistake!

Comment: I did but my problem is still not solved...the count value is always the same...

Comment: But you did not answer my question: when do you think it will be called? Put a log statement in it so you see it gets called.

Comment: The whole description of your problem lacks. You are not mentioning that you use static varianles for certain purpose. You mix int and Integer. You do not send a count value to your main activity but the main activity requests the count value from your DrawView class. You did not tell when you expect to see the increased value in th main activity. Is it at screen rotation? At startup? You call it only once in one lifecycle. What happens if you call it ofter?

Comment: @greenapps I use static variables because the getCountValue demanded that the count has to be static. I wanted to make it passable with the "public static Integer getCountValue()", I looked for something like if count increases in de DrawView the count in the MainActivity gets refreshed an the new count is there, and then it would be called more often?

When you say that the count isn't send  to the MainActivity, what do you suggest me to use?

Comment: You did not understand me. I only critisised the way you described what happened. You said "i send a count value to the main activity". Well that is not what happens. Instead the main activity requests the count value. Thats why i said `You do not send a count value to your main activity but the main activity requests the count value from your DrawView class` You are already doing that.

Comment: But you still did not explain why the touches count should be counted and never reset. What is the need? Further count is preserved for a following onCreate() as happens with screen rotations. Why did you not comment on the screen rotation i mentioned earlier? I try to understand what this is all about.

Comment: @greenapps Oh well, I'm trying my best to write something understandable, but it's hard for me, because I'm not so good in writing English.. 
Anyway I do understand you now and I'll try to edit it..

Comment: @greenapps In the MainActivity I need the count value for switching to another activity, every time count%2 == 1 the activity should switch. In the DrawView count++ is needed to differentiate between the first and the second point of the path.

Comment: But onCreate is called only once. So that's why i asked you when did should happen?

Comment: @greenapps I don't know, see that's my whole problem. I have a third class in which I have to choose diffrent paint options, I do now have to switch between the View and the ChangeActivity after every second touch. I wanted to take the count value and passing it to the Main class, and the Main class should switch to the change class after evry second touch

Comment: But your code is in onCreate. And onCreate is not called when the user touches your DrawArea view. So what is this all about? Just start your explanation again without code. Just tell what should happen when.

Comment: @greenapps So, you touch the screen and the program gets the first point, it opens another layout with buttons. Blue, Yellow, Green... You click on the button, the button contains a value and gives this value to a variable, this value is requested by the DrawView, the button, you should also get back to the other layout, now you are back and touch the screen again and the program gets the second point, with the drawPath it draws the first path now, and then you could repeat it, and you get lots of lines...

Comment: `it opens another layout` ? Is that a layout or another Activity?

Comment: @greenapps A diffrent Activity and its layout

Comment: So you have made your own view class and want that user actions with your view get noticed by the activity that uses it. You want that other activities get started and that results of those other activities are delivered to the calling activity/view. Are you able to get the choosen button value now in the MainActivity? The code you showed here is far from this all.

Comment: @greenapps I get the choosen button value directly in the View in the pointDown methode..
I made the program first so that the buttons are in the same Layout as the View, then everything worked fine!!

Now I want that the buttons are in a diffrent layout and that makes the problem...

Comment: Yes. That makes a big difference. Please do not say "the buttons are in a different layout" but "the buttons are in their own activity".

Comment: @greenapps I thought about adding the buttons to my MainActivity, and just switching between the layouts, is this maybe possible?

Comment: `just switching between the layouts` ? I do not understand what you mean by that.

Comment: @greenapps  I have the DrawLayout and the Button Layout. When you touch the screen , you change to the ButtonLayout, but remain in the same Activity, where you also handle the Button clicks..

Comment: @greenapps if (Case_A)
  setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

else if (Case_B)
  setContentView(R.layout.layout2); something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can implement listener interface.
Define interface in your view:

````
```public interface ViewCountListener {
     void onViewCountChanged(int viewCount);
}```
````

in your view add variable `ViewCountListener listener;` and method `void addListener(ViewCountListener listener)`, where you'll set the listener.

and in onTouch add:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //your code

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            count++; // count increases +1
            if (listener != null) listener.onViewCountChange(count);
```

After that add to your Activity `implements ViewCountListener`, implement `onViewCountChange(int)` method and add a field member with that counter.

Pros:

- any class (not only activity) can be a listener
- your activity can be a listener for all views your create

Cons:

- it'll work only if your view is part of your activity's context. However, you can create make holding variable in activity static and pass its value to the other activities.

Hope it helps)

Comment: I have a question: where do I have to put them? `ViewCountListener listener; and method void addListener(ViewCountListener listener)`, my way doesn't work...

Comment: ViewCountListener listener - field variable in the view. 
void addListener(ViewCountListener listener) { this.listener = listener; } - method in the view that produces events, not in your activity

Comment: Thx, that works, but I have also problems wih implementing the,   `onViewCountChange(int) ` in the Activity. I made a methode: `  public void onViewCountChange(int){
   //put something..?
  
  }` It gives me the error:  `VariableDeclaratorld expected`

 I'm sorry for my asking, but I'm not so good in working with listeners..

Comment: it should be `public void onViewCountChanged(int viewCount);' in declaration (in interface) and `public void onViewCountChanged(int viewCount) { this.viewCount += viewCount; }` in activity.

Comment: error is because you didn't add a variable's name after int